# Bizarre behaviour of number storage and equality

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I'm trying to track changes of my view's height to notify an observer of this. I am storing the view's height in a property to compare it in `-layoutSubviews`. What happens next I can't work out. It appears on Retina HD devices (6 Plus, 7 Plus), my view's height is reported as `200.00000000000003` (it is set to `200.0`).

The number puzzles me but I figure I can work around it.

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat previousHeight;
...

const CGFloat currentHeight = self.frame.size.height;
if (currentHeight != self.previousHeight) {
    self.previousHeight = currentHeight;
    DLog (@"Different");
}
```

I thought that storing both values into the same type would eradicate this issue, but the comparison still passes. That is, no matter how I try to store the current height, the if statement is pointless. Even printing the different properties in the debugger prints my property as a rounded float, and the `currentHeight` variable as the extremely precise float.

Short of manually rounding the view's height, or storing it as an integer, what else should I do? I must be missing something regarding the storage/equality of doubles and floats.

Comment: please remove c tag since this is objective-c and not c.

Comment: They appear correct in the debugger because by default they are rounded to 6 decimal places for display.

Comment: Why not compare the values after casting each to `long` or `int`?

Comment: @rmaddy No, it actually prints as "200.00000000000003"

Comment: @rmaddy As I said, that's what I'll settle on if I have to. But I wanted to understand what's going on here.

Comment: You said *"Even printing the different properties in the debugger prints my property as a rounded float"*.

Comment: @rmaddy "and the currentHeight variable as the extremely precise float". So they must be getting set to different values?

Comment: How are you printing these values in the debugger? With which command? What do you see when you run `p/x currentHeight` and `p/x self.previousHeight` (in the debugger)?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I've been using `po`. The results are 
(lldb) p/x currentHeight
(CGFloat) $2 = 0x4068ffffffffffff
(lldb) p/x self.previousHeight
(CGFloat) $3 = 0x4068ffffffffffff

Comment: As you can see, their integer values are exactly the same — why `po` is printing differently truncated values, I'm not sure, but regardless, they have the same value precisely. If you print both values to their full precision, you'll see that they are equal.

Comment: Getting the value of a floating point number precisely by printing it is rarely what you want; as you can see, different print statements might truncate sooner rather than later, making values appear equal (or different). If you're in doubt, print their bit patterns as interpreted as integers.

Comment: If you're curious about what `p/x` does, look at the following [`gdb` Output Formats document](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html): when you `p/x` a value, it interprets the bits of that value as an integer, then prints that out in hex.

Comment: `po` on the other hand, is useful in debugging Objective-C — it attempts to interpret the value you give it as a pointer to an object and print that out; it falls back to the regular `p` if what you give it if it's not an object, I believe. Still, how it interprets what you give it might be different from what you think; it's quite possible that the difference in printing styles comes from the fact that one of the variables is local, while the other is the result of a method call (getting the property).

Comment: @Ricky If you'd like, I can type this up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @ItaiFerber. But this only confuses me more. Because the numbers ARE equal, yet my if statement keeps being entered.

Comment: Sorry, I must've misread the question. Can you please post the entire code of that method, then?